# How does it return NullPointerException.?

Tags: java

```
public class TestDogs {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Dog [][] theDogs = new Dog[3][];
        System.out.println(theDogs[2][0].toString());
    }
}

class Dog{ }
```

Comment: [2D arrays](http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs231/lectures/chapter9/arrays2d.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`theDogs[2]` array is null, since you didn't initialize it. Even it you initialized it, `theDogs[2][0]` would still be null, so calling `toString` on it would still throw `NullPointerException`.

Example how to initialize the array and the Dog instance :

```
Dog [][] theDogs = new Dog[3][];
theDogs[2] = new Dog[7]; // initialize the 3rd row of theDogs 2D array
theDogs[2][0] = new Dog (); // initialize the Dog instance at the 1st column of the 3rd row
System.out.println(theDogs[2][0].toString()); // now you can execute methods of theDogs[2][0]
```

Comment: How is "Dog [][] theDogs = new Dog[3][];" different from "Dog theDogs = new Dog();"?

Comment: @arjunhegde The first initializes an array that can contain Dog[] references (i.e. arrays of Dog). Each element in the array is initialized to null. The second creates a single instance of the Dog class.

Answer (score 0):

`new Dog[3][];` creates a *new array* to hold `Dog[]` instances. You will have to add `Dog[]` instances to it.

`theDogs[2][0]` will give you NPE. Actually, `theDogs[2]` is not initialized, so this will give you NPE even before you proceed to `theDogs[2][0]`.

Comment: No, `new Dog[3][]` creates a new array to hold references to `Dog[]` instances (i.e. arrays). It's `theDogs[2]` which is null here - it doesn't get as far as a null `Dog` reference.

Comment: How is "Dog [][] theDogs = new Dog[3][];" different from "Dog theDogs = new Dog();"?